# BGI Error (5) Not enough memory to load the driver turboc++

Tags: c++, c, turbo-c++, bgi

```
int gDriver = DETECT, gMode;
initgraph(&gDriver, &gMode, "c:\\turboc3\\BGI");
int errorcode = graphresult();       // It is returning 5
```

The errorcode has value 5 which means "Not enough memory to load the driver"

How do I fix this error?

Comment: how much free memory you have (type `mem` into cmd line and see 640KB is max but if you got like 530Kb instead then you have to free up some)? you can free some by moving some drivers to high memory with himem.sys (like mouse, CD-ROM, etc) also if you got too many TSR's in memory  ... How big is the bgi driver file?  Close other applications you got in background lice NC/VC ...

Comment: Additionally, if you target DOS, I would try running your compiled program in different environments to see if there're any correlations (you can use a [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) VM with a *VirtualBox* or *VMware Player*, or experiment with [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) -- both are freely available). The error you receive may have nothing to do with your program per se.